# Python-using FOR loop to compare pairs of integers

Tags: python

I am taking a basic course in Python and have difficulty on solving the following task (NOTE: I can only use FOR loops and IF statements as that is what we have learned so far):
The user has to enter 2*n numbers, where "n" is input from the user.
Then the 1st and 2nd number form a pair as do the 3rd and 4th and so on.
I have to write simple code which compare if all pairs have the same value and if not to calculate the max difference between 2 consequent pairs.
If all pairs have equal value I must print "Yes, value={Value}". If not, I must print "No, maxdiff={Difference}".

Currently I have written the following (which doesn't work):

```
count_numbers = int(input()) * 2

sum_pair1 = 0
sum_pair2 = 0
result = 0


for i in range(0, count_numbers * 2, 2):
    sum_pair1 = int(input()) + int(input())
    sum_pair2 = int(input()) + int(input())

if sum_pair1 == sum_pair2:
    result = f"Yes, value ={sum_pair1}"
else:
    result = f"No, maxdiff={abs(sum_pair1 - sum_pair2)}"

print(result)
```

Tried writing code but cannot get it right.

Comment: Indent your *if* block and the *print()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `max_diff` to keep track of maximal difference and `are_all_equal` to tell whether all numbers are equal.

```
max_diff = 0
last_number = None
are_all_equal = True

# How many numbers would you like to enter?
numbers_count = int(input())

for _ in range(numbers_count):
    number1 = int(input())
    number2 = int(input())
        
    if are_all_equal:
        if number1 == number2:
            if last_number and last_number != number1:
                are_all_equal = False
            last_number = number1
        else:
            are_all_equal = False
    
    diff = abs(number1 - number2)
      
    if diff > max_diff:
        max_diff = diff

if are_all_equal:
    print(f"Yes, value = {last_number}")
else:
    print(f"No, maxdiff = {max_diff}")
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this way you are only comparing the numbers, right? I need to compare pairs of subsequent numbers: number1+number2 = pair 1, then number3+number4=pair2 and so on. And then I have to compare all pairs (total pairs depend on the user input) and if all are equal to print the value and if not to print the max difference between 2 subsequent pairs.

Comment: @v1dem No, I'm comparing pairs of numbers just as you said.